# Merge two video side by side ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, android-ffmpeg

I´m working on project android with ffmpeg who can merge two videos side by side and i have a problem for example the first video has 20 seconds and the second has 35 seconds when i merge them i got video has 35 seconds everytime video got the large time but i want the small
in above exmaple i want the output video has 20 seconds not 35.
my shot

```
"-i","firsth.mp4","-i","second.mp4","-filter_complex","[0:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack","-c:v","libx264","-crf","23","-preset","veryfast myoutput.mp4"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `shortest` option in [hstack](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack):

```
"-i","firsth.mp4","-i","second.mp4","-filter_complex","[0:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[l];[1:v]scale=480:640,setsar=1[r];[l][r]hstack=shortest=1","-c:v","libx264","-crf","23","-preset","veryfast","myoutput.mp4"
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with a batch script.  Get the duration of both videos using the `ffmpeg -i first.mp4` as discussed [here](https://superuser.com/questions/650291/how-to-get-video-duration-in-seconds).  Then, calculate the lower of the two values, and pass that time as the `-t` parameter when creating the video, which limits the duration of the output.  Command-line parameters are described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html).  You will have to format the time as a time duration specification, described [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax).